# Unable to install Salesforce Platform Developer maintenance package

Tags: platform-developer-1

I get the following error when i click install package for admins only for Platform Developer Maintenance exam. How to resolve it?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any apex classes or triggers in this org? Sometimes those can prevent a package being installed. Just check on that part once.

Comment: I just created that org, its pretty new one.

Comment: I would have guessed that you were installing in a Professional Edition org, or some edition without Apex.  The url doesn't look like a Trailhead org.  Since this is for Trailhead, just make sure you are logged out of all other orgs and then create a new Playground org for the exercise.

Comment: Yes, you were right, its resolved now, thank you